# How to update Express.js template in nodeclipse

Tags: node.js, express, nodeclipse

I have installed latest version of `nodeclipse` but when i create `express.js` project i found that the express version is 3.6 and the current is 4.9 so is there any way to update express template in the `nodeclipse` IDE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nodeclipse is using `express` executable (as selected in preferences) to launch it and create express project. Once you have latest `express-generator` installed

```
npm install -g express-generator
```

it would add `express` executable with the same params but for 4.x version of express

Then Eclipse Nodeclipse preferences should be updated, e.g.

`C:\Users\yourusername\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\express-generator\bin\express`

(Will be default starting from Nodeclipse 0.17)

You should co-work with other users on [issue #162](https://github.com/Nodeclipse/nodeclipse-1/issues/162)

Comment: i have downloaded latest version of express-generator but it's still using older version

Comment: Have you checked what executable is selected in Nodeclipse preferences for express? It would have old initial values, unless yu have updated.