# nodeclipse does not create express4 projects

Tags: node.js, express, nodeclipse

My nodeclipse does not create express4 projects. I downloaded the latest node.js and installed on my ubuntu. Also downloaded latest nodeclipse. But, each time I create a new node.js express project, it will still create a structure of express3 based project.

Comment: possible already answered in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26007228/how-to-update-express-js-template-in-nodeclipse

Answer (score 0):

What is new way to create projects with Express 4?

Nodeclipse just executes `express` just as you do from command line.

a. You can create new empty project, and run express4 executable.

b. Or configure Express Path in preference to point to new executable.

Take a look at sources https://github.com/Nodeclipse/nodeclipse-1/blob/master/org.nodeclipse.ui/src/org/nodeclipse/ui/wizards/ExpressProjectWizard.java#L199-L232

Comment: The CLI tool was removed from the `express` package for v4, and should now be installed using the [`express-generator`](https://github.com/expressjs/generator) package.

Comment: So `express-generator` should be configured in Preferences for Express Path

Comment: No, `express-generator` should be installed as a dependency, but once it has, the executable will still be named `express`.

Comment: Robert, give it as new answer: just install `express-generator`

Answer (score 0):

The `express` executable has been removed from the regular `express` package since v4, and has been moved to a separate package called [`express-generator`](https://github.com/expressjs/generator).

If that package is installed, it will bring back the `express` executable which should enable Nodeclipse to create new Express projects again.